# How can I get CucumberJS to recognizing my Scenario Outline parameters in a step definition?

Tags: node.js, cucumberjs

Using CucumberJS I'm trying to implement a Scenario Outline for UI testing.  Cucumber isn't recognizing or passing my arguments correctly.  Here's what I have.

test.feature

```
Scenario Outline: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format
    Given a <username> has logged into site
        Examples:
            |username      |fileName    |
            |administrator |test1.csv   |
            |userA         |step2.csv   |
```

test_step.js

```
Given('a {string} has logged into site', async function (username) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
    return this.userLogin(username);
});
```

world.js

```
'use strict';
const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber');

class testApp {
    // Write metrics data object to JSON file
    async userLogin(username) {
        await this.navigateLoginPage();
    }
}

setWorldConstructor(testApp);
```

Now when I run this, I get the following:

```
 Warnings:

1) Scenario: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format # features/importPaymentFile.feature:28
   ? Given a administrator has logged into site
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('a administrator has logged into site', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });


2) Scenario: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format # features/importPaymentFile.feature:29
   ? Given a administrator has logged into site
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('a userA has logged into site', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
             });
```

So now I'm confused.  It looks like my parameters are getting correctly read but not recognizing them in the step definitions.

Can anyone please give me some insight on how I should be implementing the Scenario Outline's parameters?

**UPATE #3 - FINAL UPDATE**
So it worked for me like this:

test.feature

```
Scenario Outline: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format
    Given a "<username>" has logged into site and uploads "<fileName>"
        Examples:
            |username      |fileName    |
            |administrator |test1.csv   |
            |userA         |step2.csv   |
```

test_step.js

```
Given('a {string} has logged into site and uploads {string}', async function (username, fileName) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
    console.log('fileName = ' + fileName);
    return this.userLogin(username);
});
```

world.js

```
'use strict';
const { setWorldConstructor } = require('cucumber');

class testApp {
    // Write metrics data object to JSON file
    async userLogin(username) {
        await this.navigateLoginPage();
    }
}

setWorldConstructor(testApp);
```

Results:

```
> . ./.env; node app.js "--feature" "importPaymentFile"

username = administrator
filename = oneStepApproval_MediaOcean.csv
.username = operations
filename = twoStepApproval_MediaOceanDan.csv
```

Sorry if I was to verbose.  I'll pair this down if told to do so :)

---

**UPDATE #1**

I tried quotes, it this didn't work.  Putting quotes around the parameter in the feature file seemed to cause the parameter to not be passed.

test.feature

```
Scenario Outline: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format
    Given a "<username>" has logged into site
        Examples:
            |username      |fileName    |
            |administrator |test1.csv   |
            |userA         |step2.csv   |
```

resulting error:

```
username = 
.username = 
.

2 scenarios (2 passed)
2 steps (2 passed)
0m00.015s
(node:16642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 7): Error: Protocol error(Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
(node:16642) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:16642) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 8): Error: Protocol error (Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Timed out while authenticating with server
at Timeout._onTimeout (/Users/huckcarignan/Desktop/sprint26/epay-test-automation/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:139:17)
at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)
```

**Update #2**

Combo 1:  & {string}

Feature File:

```
Given a <username> has logged into Site
```

Step Definition:

```
Given('a {string} has logged into Site', async function (username) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
    return this.userLogin(username);
});
```

Results:

```
? Given a administrator has logged into Site
    Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

      Given('a administrator has logged into Site', function () {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        return 'pending';
      });
```

Combo 2:  & ([^"]*)

Feature File:

```
Given a <username> has logged into Site
```

Step Definition:

```
Given('a ([^"]*) has logged into Site', async function (username) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
    return this.userLogin(username);
});
```

Results:

```
? Given a administrator has logged into Site
    Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

      Given('a administrator has logged into Site', function () {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        return 'pending';
      });
```

Combo 3: "" & "([^"]*)"

Feature File:

```
Given a "<username>" has logged into Site
```

Step Definition:

```
       Given('a "([^"]*)" has logged into Site', async function (username) {
         console.log('username = ' + username);
         return this.userLogin(username);
        });
```

Results:

```
? Given a {string} has logged into Site
    Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

      Given('a administrator has logged into Site', function () {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        return 'pending';
      });
```

Combo 4: "" & ([^"]*)

Feature File:

```
Given a <username> has logged into Site
```

Step Definition:

```
Given('a "([^"]*)" has logged into Site', async function (username) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
       return this.userLogin(username);
    });
```

Results:

```
? Given a {string} has logged into Site
    Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

      Given('a administrator has logged into Site', function () {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        return 'pending';
      });
```

Combo 5: "" & {string}  **THE WINNER - sort of**

Feature File:

```
Given a <username> has logged into Site
```

Step Definition:

```
Given('a "([^"]*)" has logged into Site', async function (string) {
    console.log('username = ' + string);
    return this.userLogin(string);
});
```

Results:

```
username = administrator
.

1 scenarios (1 passed)
1 steps (1 passed)
0m01.637s;
```

Sooooo...this works, multiple parameters are handled by order - I'll put my results at the very top

Answer (score 2):

I used regular expressions

So for your example:

```
Scenario Outline: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format
    Given a <username> has logged into site
        Examples:
            |username      |fileName    |
            |administrator |test1.csv   |
            |userA         |step2.csv   |
```

Then in the code I would do:

```
Given(/^a (.*) has logged into site$/, async function (username) {
    console.log('username = ' + username);
    return this.userLogin(username);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scenario Outline: User with permissions can Import Payment files with any file format
Given a "<username>" has logged into site
    Examples:
        |username      |fileName    |
        |administrator |test1.csv   |
        |userA         |step2.csv   |
```

Add quotes to the example,"" it could be that cucumber is expecting a string parameter to be passed in which is not the case in your test

Comment: I tried quotes, and that didn't work.  I updated this above.

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan 
Your updated answer does not include the quotes..I'm guessing you ran with quotes but just made a mistake on the response here.
It looks like it did work and the step is no longer undefined. The original issue looks like it is resolved but another issue.

Also, you should use async-await on the async functions.

Comment: Doh!  Yea, I did run it with quotes but didn't cut&paste the quoted version in.  Thanks for catching that.  I updated the above to reflect that.

Comment: return this.userLogin(username);

This should be  
  
 `return await this.userLogin(username);`